# Regex grouping including subgroups of ors and maintaining invariant of capture count

Tags: regex, pcre

FWIW I am using OCaml bindings to Pcre.

(I will use a json like object to get my point across)

I have a structure like:

```
{"foo":[<valid_regex_pattern>],
 "bar":[<valid_regex_pattern>],
 "baz":[<valid_regex_pattern_1, valid_regex_pattern_2]}
```

I need to keep make sure that each valid_regex_pattern says as one group, so I am iterating over the structure and for the ones that have an array of just 1 element, I am wrapping them in `(?>...)` where the `...` is a `<valid_regex_pattern>`. For example:

`"(?>googletagmanager\\.com/ns\\.html[^>]+></iframe>)"`

For the arrays that have more than one pattern, I am "or-ing" them and then wrapping them in `(?>...)` as well, for example:

`"(?>((<div class=\"[^\"]*parbase)|(<div[^>]+data-component-path=\"[^\"+]jcr:)))"`

After doing this I have my regexes ready and I combine them then so that I end up having something like

`((?>((<style>/\*!\* Bootstrap v(\d\.\d\.\d))|(<link[^>]+?href="[^"]+bootstrap(?:\.min)?\.css)|(<div [^>]*class="[^"]*col-(?:xs|sm|md|lg)-\d{1,2}) )))|((?><iframe src="[^>]+tumblr\.com))`

Finally the problem. Pcre gives me back too many results, in this example I would expect three results back, but PCRE gives me back more than 3. I assume this is because I am not doing the grouping correctly of the combined array regexes. I need the number of results to match the number of initial array in the initial json-like structure.

I'm not sure if I'm getting too many back as a result of not using correct flags, or the grouping is off.

Comment: `I would expect three results back, PCRE gives me back more than 3` It's not clear what you mean by 3 results. Do you mean the capturing groups? What is the expected result? What you get is probably because you have capturing groups in the pattern you get from foo, bar and baz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capture group amount is equal to the parenthesis structure count and **not changed** by the presence of alternations. Which is why, if you add together different regexes with capture groups by alternations, you will have more groups than you'd like and you either have to change the regex or modify the program working with it.

Now, imagine you have a regex `(one)` to capture `one` and a different regex `(other)` to capture `other`. On each of their respective uses, `one` and `other` are returned as `$1` (the first capture group). When you combine them, making `(one)|(other)`, there are two capture groups, `$1` for `one` and `$2` for `other`, as seen [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/zN7dV4/1) , so you have to change your program to work with 2 capture groups OR change the regex.

If you want both `one` and `other` to be just one capture group, you can do something like `((?:one)|(?:other))` or `(one|other)` https://regex101.com/r/zN7dV4/2 . It's easier to add things than to remove them, so `((?:one)|(?:other))` is what I would do.

So i tried out your code (besides having an unescaped `/`), it gave me 7 capture groups due to the alternations. I did the same thing (made an enclosing group and made the each respective group non-capturing) and it got me 3 results, but I can't make tests to see if they're what you want. `((?:(?>((<style>\/\*!\* Bootstrap v(\d\.\d\.\d))|(?:<link[^>]+?href="[^"]+bootstrap(?:\.min)?\.css)|(?:<div [^>]*class="[^"]*col-(?:xs|sm|md|lg)-\d{1,2}) )))|(?:(?><iframe src="[^>]+tumblr\.com)))`